# Incorrect string value errors in AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption, encoding, aes

I'm introducing myself to the encryption functions in MYSQL.

Just wrote a simple SQL statement to add an encrypted entry into a field

```
INSERT INTO test_table (field1) VALUES(aes_encrypt('fieldentry','password'))
```

When I execute the SQL I get the following error

> Error 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xC7\xE13\xC4\xF4!...' for column 'field1' at row 1 SQL Statement - CHANGE COLUMN `field1` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT ''

Now I've read it may have something to do with CHARACTER SET, and tried changing it from utf8-default collation to utf8mb4 - default collation as recommended, but that didnt make any difference.

I've also tried changing the column type from VARCHAR to VARBINARY. The SQL statement then ran successfully, however, when I tried the following to retreive the data:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(field1, '12345') AS endata FROM test_table
    Do Until rst.EOF 
        Response.Write(rst("endata"))
        rst.movenext
    Loop
```

The loop runs but no values are returned (blank lines)

I'm just looking for a straightforward what to encrypt and then decrypt my data using a password in the function AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> `AES_ENCRYPT() encrypts a string and returns a binary string.`
>   AES_DECRYPT() decrypts the encrypted string and returns the original
>   string.

So you should change the type of `field1`,`firstname` from `VARCHAR(255)`to `VARBINARY(255)`. It will fix the issue..

**EDIT :** For type missmatch.. please try this..

```
SELECT *, 
       CAST(AES_DECRYPT(field1, 'mypassword') AS CHAR(50)) end_data
FROM   user
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks. The AES_ENCRYPT() works fine storing the data, however, the AES_DECRYPT() is returning a Type Mismatch.

SELECT id, AES_DECRYPT(field1, 'mypassword') AS endata FROM test_table

Response.Write(rst("endata") & "<br>")

Comment: Thanks Subin, perfect solution.

Comment: What if I have already data in the column and I want to update that column to replace data with their encryption? If I converted the column from VARCHAR to VARBINARY what would happen to the original data?

Comment: @Ahmedn1 integers and varchars will be converted to a string when you change the column to a blob or binary. But if you want to make sure, just create a table with some data and change the colum types to see what happends.